# Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64

Tags: linux, gdb, core-file

I'm trying to analyze core dump file as I want to know why oom-killer kills my application. I use gdb to analyze the core dump file but always when I try to run gdb on my core dump, I get the following warning message:

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
```

GDP version :
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-83.el6)

Trying to `debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64` package results in:

```
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-23.el6_7.x86_64
No debuginfo packages available to instal
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get the following warning message

The warning message tells you *exactly* how to solve it:

```
sudo debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
```

You can also safely ignore it.

Comment: I know it tells me how to solve it, but it did not work it gives me the following message:                                                                               Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-23.el6_7.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-23.el6_7.x86_64
No debuginfo packages available to install

Comment: @DaoudShaheen You asked your question very poorly by not stating relevant info. I've edited it. You may get a better answer on ServerFault.